# Debezium with AWS MSK NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, debezium, amazon-msk

I have a running debezium cluster in AWS, no issues with that. I want to give a try with AWS MSK. So  I launched a cluster. Then I launched an EC2 for running my connectors.

Then installed confluent-kafka

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install confluent-platform-2.12
```

By default the AWS MSK doesn't have schema registry, So I configured it from the connector EC2
Schema registry conf file:

```
kafkastore.connection.url=z-1.bhuvi-XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:2181,z-3.bhuvi-XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:2181,z-2.bhuvi-XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:2181


kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://b-2.bhuvi-XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:9092,PLAINTEXT://b-4.bhuvi-XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:9092,PLAINTEXT://b-1.bhuvi-XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:9092
```

Then `/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties` file

```
bootstrap.servers=b-4.bhuvi-XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:9092,b-3.bhuvi-XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:9092,b-2.bhuvi-XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:9092

plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components
```

### Install connector:

```
confluent-hub install debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:latest
```

#### start the service

```
systemctl start confluent-schema-registry
systemctl start confluent-connect-distributed
```

Now everything started. Then I created a mysql.json file.

```
{
    "name": "mysql-connector-db01",
    "config": {
        "name": "mysql-connector-db01",
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.server.id": "1",
        "tasks.max": "3",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "172.31.47.152:9092,172.31.38.158:9092,172.31.46.207:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.mysql",
        "database.server.name": "mysql-db01",
        "database.hostname": "172.31.84.129",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "bhuvi",
        "database.password": "my_stong_password",
        "database.whitelist": "proddb,test",
        "internal.key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "internal.value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState"
        "transforms.unwrap.add.source.fields": "ts_ms",
    }
}
```

#### Create debezium connector

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors -d @mysql.josn
```

Then its stated giving this error in the connector EC2.

```
Dec 20 11:42:36 ip-172-31-44-220 connect-distributed[2630]: [2019-12-20 11:42:36,290] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 844 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147482809 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:637)
Dec 20 11:42:36 ip-172-31-44-220 connect-distributed[2630]: [2019-12-20 11:42:36,391] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 845 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147482808 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:637)
Dec 20 11:42:36 ip-172-31-44-220 connect-distributed[2630]: [2019-12-20 11:42:36,492] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 846 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147482807 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:637)
Dec 20 11:42:36 ip-172-31-44-220 connect-distributed[2630]: [2019-12-20 11:42:36,593] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 847 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147482806 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:637)
```

It never stops this error message.

Describe of connect-configs

```
Topic:connect-configs   PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:cleanup.policy=compact
        Topic: connect-configs  Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
```

Comment: Please describe the connect-configs topic

Comment: I'll post that in a while, but i remember it's replica factor is 3 i guess

Comment: @cricket_007 question updated

Comment: Is there a reason that topic doesn't have more than one replica?

Comment: I don't know and how this is created

Comment: `config.storage.replication.factor` . It defaults to 3, so I don't know how you got 1 unless you set it yourself https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs

Comment: No, from the kafka side I didn't touch anything.

Comment: That property is in the `connect-distributed.properties` , not `server.properties`

Comment: I'll check this setting now

Comment: Just checked, the 1 is the default value there. I changed it to 3, but still the same error

Comment: I removed all the connect-* topics and changed the replication factor to 3, now it worked. Thanks a lot. But I don't know why it was not working with 1? It'll great if you help me to understand this

Comment: It's possible that the producer used within Kafka Connect is using an ack configuration or min ISR as higher than 1. Those are the only two situations where I've seen that error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MSK sets `min.in.sync.replicas` to 2 for all topics by default (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-default-configuration.html)

It possible that Kafka Connect is producing using ACKs="all" and, since you only have one copy of your topic, it never achieves enough quorum.

Comment: Yes, by default it's using "ACKs=all" (https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#acks) and "offsets.topic.replication.factor=3" (https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#offsets.topic.replication.factor)

So, by default kafka connector requires a minimum of 3 nodes (1 leader + 2 replicas).

Comment: You can also change it in the Kafka-connect level with:
offset.storage.replication.factor, config.storage.replication.factor, status.storage.replication.factor=1
and if running with Docker:
CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR,  CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR
CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR

set the value to be the save as your MSK "min.insync.replicas"

Comment: I changed all the values mentioned by @shlomiLan to 2 (the value of `min.insync.replicas` by default in MSK), and it worked!