# kafka producer WARNING: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS Got error produce response with correlation id on topic-partition mytopic-events-0, retrying

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We are seeing this warning 10 times a second in debezium-mysql-connector logs:

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | connect-distributed-offsets] 
WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender - 
[Producer clientId=connect-distributed-offsets] Got error produce response with 
correlation id 34626 on topic-partition 
debezium-events-offset-dev-topic-events2-0, retrying (2147449048 attempts left). 
Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS
```

Here are the producer-side config:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - Idempotence will be disabled because acks is set to 1, not set to 'all'."
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values:"
"acks = 1"
"auto.include.jmx.reporter = true"
"batch.size = 32768"
"bootstrap.servers = [b-1.eventsmskafka.qgfgzh.c14.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092, b-2.eventsmskafka.qgfgzh.c14.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092, b-3.eventsmskafka.qgfgzh.c14.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092]"
"buffer.memory = 1048576"
"client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips"
"client.id = debezium-cdc-events2-schemahistory"
"compression.type = none"
"connections.max.idle.ms = 540000"
"delivery.timeout.ms = 120000"
"enable.idempotence = false"
"interceptor.classes = []"
"key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
"linger.ms = 0"
"max.block.ms = 10000"
"max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5"
"max.request.size = 1048576"
"metadata.max.age.ms = 300000"
"metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000"
"metric.reporters = []"
"metrics.num.samples = 2"
"metrics.recording.level = INFO"
"metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000"
"partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true"
"partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 0"
"partitioner.class = null"
"partitioner.ignore.keys = false"
"receive.buffer.bytes = 32768"
"reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000"
"reconnect.backoff.ms = 50"
"request.timeout.ms = 30000"
"retries = 1"
"retry.backoff.ms = 100"
"sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null"
"sasl.jaas.config = null"
"sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit"
"sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000"
"sasl.kerberos.service.name = null"
"sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05"
"sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8"
"sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null"
"sasl.login.class = null"
"sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null"
"sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null"
"sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300"
"sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60"
"sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8"
"sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05"
"sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000"
"sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100"
"sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI"
"sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30"
"sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null"
"sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null"
"sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000"
"sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000"
"sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100"
"sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null"
"sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope"
"sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub"
"sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null"
"security.protocol = PLAINTEXT"
"security.providers = null"
"send.buffer.bytes = 131072"
"socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000"
"socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000"
"ssl.cipher.suites = null"
"ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]"
"ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https"
"ssl.engine.factory.class = null"
"ssl.key.password = null"
"ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509"
"ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null"
"ssl.keystore.key = null"
"ssl.keystore.location = null"
"ssl.keystore.password = null"
"ssl.keystore.type = JKS"
"ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3"
"ssl.provider = null"
"ssl.secure.random.implementation = null"
"ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX"
"ssl.truststore.certificates = null"
"ssl.truststore.location = null"
"ssl.truststore.password = null"
"ssl.truststore.type = JKS"
"transaction.timeout.ms = 60000"
"transactional.id = null"
"value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

That producer config isn't what you need to look at (the client ids are different than your logs).

You need to look at your Debezium / Kafka Connect worker config, for `offsets.storage.topic=connect-distributed-offsets`. The error is saying that this topic does not have healthy replicas (also see `offset.storage.replication.factor`)

Use this to check the ISR list

```
kafka-topics --describe --topic=connect-distributed-offsets
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is gone after we increased the replica count of the offset's topic to 3 and partitions to 4. This error was occuring when replica count and partitions were being configured as 1. We got the idea of increasing replica count while discussing the solution at [Debezium with AWS MSK NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424863/debezium-with-aws-msk-not-enough-replicas).